# Is something wrong with this php GD code?

Tags: php, gd

```
     if ($img = @imagecreatefromjpeg('./images/upload/13/1.JPG')) {

         imagejpeg($img, $path, 100);
            imagedestroy($img);

     } else {

         die ("image was not created or saved");

     }
```

I'm getting the message:

Warning: imagejpeg(): 8 is not a valid Image resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\invivid\libraries\photograph_classes.php  on line 276

Warning: imagedestroy(): 8 is not a valid Image resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\invivid\libraries\photograph_classes.php on line 277

The image is being created initially, we know this from the if statement, but why doesn't imagejpeg or imagedestroy work properly?

Solution: Ok, I think it had something to do with an incorrect $path variable, it seems to be working fine now.

Comment: Strange, but try removing the @ first.

Comment: something's wrong with your GD php code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve never used it like that (without creating a new image, doing some manipulation, etc.), but it seems the manual is a bit vague: [imagecreatefromjpeg](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php) returns an *image resource identifier* and [imagejpeg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) needs an *image resource, returned by one of the image creation functions*. It certainly looks the same, but perhaps they are not.

Comment: imagecreatefromjpeg() **reads** jpeg file into memory (as a gdimage resource) and imagejpeg() **writes** a jpeg binairy (from a gdimage)

Comment: That´s what I thought, although the manual isn´t that clear (image resource vs image resource identifier). Don't see anything else that´s wrong though...

Comment: selecting this as an answer to get this post out of the way

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php) on imagecreatefromjpeg (although this seems particulary implausible):

```
imagecreatefromJPEG is for .JPEG and .JPG ending
&
imagecreatefromjpeg is for .jpeg and .jpg ending.

That function is case sensitive.
```

Another worthwhile thing to try could be setting

```
ini_set('gd.jpeg_ignore_warning', 1);
```

and see if that solves presumed issues with corrupted images.

Comment: even IF the function is case-sensitive (which indeed is mentioned in the **comments**), Whats the difference between a .jpg and a .JPG file?!?

Comment: @Bob Fanger: yes, that's why I added the 'particulary implausible' part ;-)